# Update / EXISTS or MERGE for better performance? Slow updating on big table (millions of records)

Tags: database, oracle, performance, indexing, plsql

I need some help with some performance issues:

I have a table CONTRATOS with 27 millions of records. This table has multiple columns but the important ones are: CONTRATO, CODIGO_ORIGEN.

It can exist more than one CONTRATO for each CODIGO_ORIGEN so i need to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CODIGO_ORIGEN,
    FIRST_VALUE(CONTRATO) OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_ORIGEN ORDER BY FECHA DESC) MAX_CONTRATO
FROM TABLE CONTRATOS;
```

After this we have 6 millions of records, the good ones...

What i need to do is update the "NOT FOUND" records (CONTRATO) in the table CONTRATOS with the value 'E' on the column ESTADO.

At first, i tried to do it everything in one step (query):

```
UPDATE / NOT EXISTS METHOD
--------------------------

    UPDATE CONTRATOS C
    SET ESTADO = 'E'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                CODIGO_ORIGEN,
                FIRST_VALUE(CONTRATO) OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_ORIGEN ORDER BY FECHA DESC) MAX_CONTRATO
            FROM TABLE CONTRATOS
        ) C2
        WHERE C.CONTRATO = C2.MAX_CONTRATO
    );

MERGE METHOD
---------------

    MERGE INTO CONTRATOS C
    USING 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            CODIGO_ORIGEN,
            FIRST_VALUE(CONTRATO) OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_ORIGEN ORDER BY FECHA DESC) MAX_CONTRATO
        FROM TABLE CONTRATOS
    ) C2 ON (C.CONTRATO = C2.MAX_CONTRATO)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ESTADO = 'E';
```

But after seeing that it was too slow (both methods) i tried to do it using a temporal table where i can insert the valid rows: TEMP_CONTRATOS

```
    Note: This point goes pretty fast (15 min)

    INSERT INTO TEMP_CONTRATOS (MAX_CONTRATO, CODIGO_ORIGEN)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
            CODIGO_ORIGEN,
            FIRST_VALUE(CONTRATO) OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_ORIGEN ORDER BY FECHA DESC) MAX_CONTRATO
    FROM TABLE CONTRATOS;

    Note: Here is the problem again

    UPDATE CONTRATOS C
    SET ESTADO = 'E'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM TEMP_CONTRATOS TMP
        WHERE C.CONTRATO = TMP.MAX_CONTRATO
    );
```

I have an index on both tables with the columns (CONTRATO/MAX_CONTRATO and CODIGO_ORIGEN) so i can improve the performance (right?) but im still getting too slow results...

The execution plan gives me over 700.000 of cost for 27 millions of records... Is it too much or is it ok considering the amount of records? It´s doing a TABLE FULL SCAN of both tables.

Is it a good idea using hints? is it a good idea going through indexes?... What is the best option? using Merge or Exists/Not exists / Not in??

Also, i´m not sure about creating an index for the ESTADO column because im updating that field and i read it´s not a good idea to create a index in a column where you perform updates... but i have to do a lot of queries joining with it.

Im using the V$SESSION_LONGOPS view and the session view of the sysdba user  to monitorize the process... Any better alternative?

I don´t know if i forget something important, i guess i do.

Bring me some light please. Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Regards.

Comment: How may rows (roughly) do you expect to be updated?

Comment: I expect to update 20 millions of records: there are 27 million in total,  6,5 millions are unique... So..  20 million should be affected.

Comment: Can you add the execution plan for your last try? With 6M rows in the temp table, you better not have an indexed access plan (i.e. a NL join).

Comment: You are probably re-writing the merge as a CTAS (Create Table... as select);  a transformation vs modification. It will be faster, you can benefit from compression; you can use direct path and employ parallelism if you have capacity.

Comment: The latest thing that I was trying was to update the ones who match with the temporal table instead of updating the ones who doesn't match.. This way we are doing an update of 7 millions of records instead of 20 millions... And then update the rest of them as not found.. I don't know if i am explaining well.. Am i? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and explain my thinking using the standard EMP table.

The principle is that rather than updating 20M rows out of 27M, it will be more efficient to recreate the 27M row table with the correct data. A very trivial example of this "modification to transformation" would be something like:

```
update emp
set sal=sal*1.1
where deptno=20
```

becomes

```
create table empnew as
select empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate, comm, deptno
  , case when deptno=20 then sal*1.1
         else sal
    end as sal
from emp
```

Then you rename the tables.

In your example, you are looking for "missing" rows. A technique for this is to use an outer join and the look for NULLs in the key.

So if I have a copy of the `emp` table called `tempemp`, then I could write a query something like:

```
select nvl( t.deptno, -1 ) status, t.*, e.*
from emp e
left join 
    ( select distinct deptno
    , first_value( hiredate ) over (partition by deptno order by sal ) fv
    from tempemp ) t
on t.fv = e.hiredate
```

Here I am detecting the "missing" values and setting the status column to -1.

In your case, I think you can write your query something like

```
select nvl( c1.contracto, 'E' ) estado, c2.*, c1.*
from CONTRATOS c1
left join
    ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                CODIGO_ORIGEN,
                FIRST_VALUE(CONTRATO) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY CODIGO_ORIGEN 
                      ORDER BY FECHA DESC) MAX_CONTRATO
            FROM  CONTRATOS
     ) c2
on C.CONTRATO = C2.MAX_CONTRATO
```

If this is correct, then you can turn this into a CREATE TABLE AS (CTAS) statement. At this point, you can then take advantage of parallel execution, direct path loading and nologging.

I hope this is helpful

Comment: BobC, first of all, thank you for spending your time trying to help :)

I understand your point but:

The CONTRATOS table is part of a batch process that i need to mantain. I can create new tables but the most correct would be to keep the logic in the CONTRATOS table as i said… This table has other indexes and this is just one validation of many others.

CONTRATOS table is a table with all the accounts of the clients, this table has 27 millions of records but only 7 millions are relevant. The other 20 millions need to be marked by setting the value 'E' on the ESTADO column.

Comment: If it's part of a batch process, then that is even more reason to use the transformation technique. I would suggest you at least prototype it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this helps ..

```
    merge into contratos c
            using 
            (   select /*+ parallel */ rowid rw,
                    codigo_origen, 
                    first_value(contrato) over (partition by codigo_origen order by fecha desc) max_contrato
                from contratos
            ) c2 on (c.contrato <> c2.max_contrato -- "NOT FOUND" records
                    and c.rowid = c2.rw
            ) when matched then update set estado = 'E'
            ;
```

Also, you may want to gather stats to let the optimizer choose the best plan

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! i will take a look to your solution

Answer (score 0):

Just to followup up on the benefits of transformation vs modification. I created a "bigemp" table with 29 million rows. I then performed un update, that will modify about 20 million of those rows:

```
update bigemp
set sal=sal*1.1
where mod( empno, 10 ) > 2
```

This took 1053 seconds

Using the transformation technique:

```
create table bigempNew
as
select empno, ename, job, mgr, hiredate
    case when( mod( empno,10 ) > 2 ) then sal * 1.1
         else sal
    end as sal
    , comm, deptno
from bigemp
```

This took 31s

This was all done serially (without using parallel execution). This is why I advocate this technique.

Comment: Hi BobC, Yes, i decided to use this technique and i got a better performance on my process. In fact i will need to get familiar with it because i have learn that updates and big tables are not good friends. Thank you for your time.